# php make sql query. but table not updated?

Tags: php

I used old structure. I don't use this anymore because very complicated
Problem is fixed.

I've class that updates table bu passed arguments in control function

```
<?php

class updte extends ayar
{
    function control($adi = null, $baslik = null, $acikla = null, $hakki = null, $telifx = null, $logoc = null)
    {
        $siteadi = trim($adi);
        $sitebaslik = trim($baslik);
        $aciklama = trim($acikla);
        $hakkinda = trim($hakki);
        $telif = trim($telifx);
        $logo = trim($logoc);

        $durumsor = array();
        $extsor = array();
        $degersor = array();
        if (isset($siteadi)) {
            $isle = self::siteadi($siteadi);
            array_push($durumsor, $isle["sorgu"]);
            array_push($extsor, $isle["ext"]);
            array_push($degersor, $isle["deger"]);
        }
        if (isset($sitebaslik)) {
            $isle = self::sitebaslik($sitebaslik);
            array_push($durumsor, $isle["sorgu"]);
            array_push($extsor, $isle["ext"]);
            array_push($degersor, $isle["deger"]);
        }
        if (isset($aciklama)) {
            $isle = self::aciklama($aciklama);
            array_push($durumsor, $isle["sorgu"]);
            array_push($extsor, $isle["ext"]);
            array_push($degersor, $isle["deger"]);
        }
        if (isset($hakkinda)) {
            $isle = self::hakkinda($hakkinda);
            array_push($durumsor, $isle["sorgu"]);
            array_push($extsor, $isle["ext"]);
            array_push($degersor, $isle["deger"]);
        }
        if (isset($telif)) {
            $isle = self::telif($telif);
            array_push($durumsor, $isle["sorgu"]);
            array_push($extsor, $isle["ext"]);
            array_push($degersor, $isle["deger"]);
        }
        if (isset($logo)) {
            $isle = self::favicon($logo);
            array_push($durumsor, $isle["sorgu"]);
            array_push($extsor, $isle["ext"]);
            array_push($degersor, $isle["deger"]);
        }
        if (!isset($durumsor[0])) {
            $hata = "K-0002";
            $durum = "Null query";
            return (array("err" => $hata, "status" => $durum));
        } else {
            $hata = null;
            $sx = COUNT($durumsor);
            $sb = $sx - 1;//Dizi değerden geldiği için dizilerde indis 0 dan başladığı için 1 eksik çekiyoruz
            for ($a = 0; $a <= $sb; $a++) {
                if ($a == 0) {
                    $sql = "" . $durumsor[$a] . ",";
                    $ext = "\"" . $extsor[$a] . "\"=>\"" . $degersor[$a] . "\",";
                } elseif ($a != $sb) {
                    $sql .= $durumsor[$a] . ",";
                    $ext .= "\"" . $extsor[$a] . "\"=>\"" . $degersor[$a] . "\",";
                } else {
                    $sql .= $durumsor[$a] . "";
                    $ext .= "\"" . $extsor[$a] . "\"=>\"" . $degersor[$a] . "\"";
                }
            }
            //return(array($sql,$ext));
            return self::update($sql, $ext);
        }


    }

    private function update($sql, $ext)
    {
        try {
            $ssql = "\"update siteconfig set " . $sql . "\"";
            $dizi = array($ext);
            $sor = $this->vt()->prepare($ssql);
            $sor->execute(array($ext));
            $durum = "successful";
        } catch (PDOException $i) {
            $hata = "K-0003";
            $durum = "Error Detail " . $i->getMessage();
        }
        if (!isset($hata)) {
            return (array("durum" => $durum, $dizi, $ssql));
        } else {
            return (array("hata" => $hata, "durum" => $durum));
        }
    }

    private function siteadi($i)
    {
        $stn = "siteadi=:siteadial";
        $ext = "siteadial";
        return (array("sorgu" => $stn, "ext" => $ext, "deger" => $i));
    }

    private function sitebaslik($i)
    {
        $stn = "slogan=:sitebaslik";
        $ext = "sitebaslik";
        return (array("sorgu" => $stn, "ext" => $ext, "deger" => $i));
    }

    private function aciklama($i)
    {
        $stn = "description=:acikla";
        $ext = "acikla";
        return (array("sorgu" => $stn, "ext" => $ext, "deger" => $i));
    }

    private function hakkinda($i)
    {
        $stn = "hakkinda=:hakkindalani";
        $ext = "hakkindalani";
        return (array("sorgu" => $stn, "ext" => $ext, "deger" => $i));

    }

    private function telif($i)
    {
        $stn = "copright=:telif";
        $ext = "telif";
        return (array("sorgu" => $stn, "ext" => $ext, "deger" => $i));
    }

    private function favicon($i)
    {
        $stn = "logo=:favicon";
        $ext = "favicon";
        return (array("sorgu" => $stn, "ext" => $ext, "deger" => $i));
    }

}
```

But my problem is that when I trying to call update table, I get PDO Exception like:

```
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\hesapla\kutuphane\sinif\ayar2.sinif.php on line 148
```

I tried to debug the arguments that I pass to `self::update($sql, $ext)`.

So here they are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "update siteconfig set siteadi=:siteadial,slogan=:sitebaslik,description=:acikla,hakkinda=:hakkindalani,copright=:telif,logo=:favicon"
    [1] => "siteadial"=>"Acilsağlık.Net","sitebaslik"=>"Sağlık Hesaplama Araçlarıaa","acikla"=>"","hakkindalani"=>"","telif"=>"Tüm hakları saklıdır ","favicon"=>""
)
```

Comment: no idea what the question is

Comment: `Sorry php pdo sql query idea?` What's your actual programming problem? Add [mcve]

Comment: $sql variable make sql query but database not updated @Dagon

Comment: `$ssql="\"update siteconfig set ".$sql."\"";` Excess quotes here.

Comment: Also, `$ext` should be array, not a string that looks like array.

Comment: @vp_arth Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\hesapla\kutuphane\sinif\ayar2.sinif.php on line 148 
problem:
<pre>update siteayar set siteadi=:siteadial,slogan=:sitebaslik,description=:acikla,hakkinda=:hakkindalani,copright=:telif,logo=:favicon<pre> quotes

Comment: ^ [Edit that](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38064350/edit) error into the question please.

Comment: `$ext = array(':siteadial' => 'someval', ...); ... $sor->execute($ext);`

Comment: @davulgaafyon Your problem is with count of arguments passed to query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error says:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
>   number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

so as You put in Your answer:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "update siteconfig set siteadi=:siteadial,slogan=:sitebaslik,description=:acikla,hakkinda=:hakkindalani,copright=:telif,logo=:favicon"
    [1] => "siteadial"=>"Acilsağlık.Net","sitebaslik"=>"Sağlık Hesaplama Araçlarıaa","acikla"=>"","hakkindalani"=>"","telif"=>"Tüm hakları saklıdır ","favicon"=>""
)
```

See [1] You're passing string, not an array.

So here is solution:

change this:

```
else
{
    $hata=null;
    $sx=COUNT($durumsor);
    $sb=$sx-1;//Dizi değerden geldiği için dizilerde indis 0 dan başladığı için 1 eksik çekiyoruz
    for($a=0; $a<=$sb; $a++)
    {
        if($a==0)
        {
            $sql="".$durumsor[$a].",";
            $ext="\"".$extsor[$a]."\"=>\"".$degersor[$a]."\",";                 
        }
        elseif($a!=$sb)
        {
            $sql    .= $durumsor[$a].",";
            $ext    .= "\"".$extsor[$a]."\"=>\"".$degersor[$a]."\",";
        }
        else
        {
                $sql .= $durumsor[$a]."";
                $ext .= "\"".$extsor[$a]."\"=>\"".$degersor[$a]."\"";
        }
    }
//return(array($sql,$ext));
return self::update($sql,$ext);
}
```

to this:

```
else {
  $sql = array();
  $ext = array();
  for ($a = 0; $a < count($durumsor); $a++) {
    $sql[] = $durumsor[$a];
    $ext[$extsor[$a]] = $degersor[$a];
  }
  $sql = implode(', ', $sql);

  return self::update($sql, $ext);
}
```

Comment: $sor->execute(array($ext)); I make array posibble? 
$ext="siteadial"=>"Acilsağlık.Net","sitebaslik"=>"Sağlık Hesaplama Araçlarıaa","acikla"=>"","hakkindalani"=>"","telif"=>"Tüm hakları saklıdır ","favicon"=>"";
maybe problem $ssql query quote but no solution :(

Comment: @davulgaafyon please change Your code as in my answer

Comment: @davulgaafyon check this screenshot: http://joxi.ru/8An33dHqvZ3QrO

Comment: Last answer :)
Do you think that this method is safe?

Comment: @davulgaafyon as You use PDO with placeholders PDO itself sanitize arguments, so it's safe against sql injections. But actually I prefer to use normal ORMs like: Eloquent, Doctrine, RedBean. Because I do not write sql queries, most of job done by Models in ORM itself. But I see You're newbie, so better don't waste time for learning, because You've to do Your job. Next time start using normal php framework, like: Phalcon, Symfony2, Laravel, Slim or any framework You will like. You'll see frameworks and ORMs that shipped with them give You more powers to work with app logic and data

Comment: thanks num8er yes php newbie but php  curious and lovers :)  I am improving myself.
Try Codelintiger very complicated :( as soon learn Lavarel because maybe new and functional
good bye